# from last night to today till 11am IST, I could not access stackoverflow site. It just displays nothing

Tags: support, stack-overflow

from last night to today till 11am IST, I could not access stackoverflow site. It just displays nothing.I faced this problem before some days.. what is the problem?

EDIT:- Facing Same kind of problem again..

Comment: anybdy facing the same problem?? or site loads for you correctly, just say here that it loads correctly. So that I can come to conclusion sthat where the problem resides

Comment: Everything's fine here.

Comment: Have you tried a traceroute to stackoverflow.com?  Everything is fine for me.

Comment: Thanks everybody for nice response.  
Traceroute? How can I do this..

Answer (score 3):

A very useful tool in cases like this is http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ which allows you to see if the site is accessible from at least one other place on the internet.

Comment: The fun thing is, that site isn't accessible to me :)

Comment: Obviously somebody needs to create a http://isdownforeveryoneorjustmedownforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Even today also in morning I cannot access.

Comment: I will check with this link whenever it not displays to me and post the results here

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. Can you access the site through a proxy? Maybe it's your internet settings, or your ISP's that are affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to meta, Super User, and Server Fault?

What does traceroute to stackoverflow.com say?

Comment: I can only view blog.stackoverflow.com. I cannot view stackoverflow during morning.